# Broadleaf - Heat Clinic Demo - Build Fails

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I followed the documentation for starting the Broadleaf Heat Clinic demo, and the build fails due to dependency missing from a Broadleaf server.  It appears that it's expecting to find the folder http://nexus.broadleafcommerce.org/nexus/content/groups/community-snapshots/com/mycompany-community/boot-community-demo-core, which does not exist.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project boot-community-demo-admin: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mycompany-community:boot-community-demo-admin:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.mycompany-community:boot-community-demo-core:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT in public snapshots (http://nexus.broadleafcommerce.org/nexus/content/groups/community-snapshots/)

Please advise regarding how to remedy.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you haven't structured properly your folders and you are trying to run it from cmd line. Try running it from  an IDE (eclipse for instance) following these guidelines:

https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/getting-started/ide-setup/eclipse-setup

it's extremely easy and you shouldn't face any problem.

Comment: It was even more lame than that... I first failed to initially run install at the root folder level.  Second, I had to downgrade from Java 11 to Java 8.  As an aside, I am running this on a CentOS 7.6 server with the latest version of Maven.